# Spacewalk kickstart installation does not automatically begin until the enter key is pressed

Tags: centos7, pxe-boot, kickstart, spacewalk

I am trying to automate the linux installation process using **Spacewalk 2.10.** Everything else seems to be working, except I have to select the `boot` option by manually pressing the `enter` key. Otherwise, Automatic boot time is reset and the installation does not start.

Does anyone have any idea what can be the issue or how can we tweak this? I have deleted the `default menu entry` named `local` which tries to boot the system into local disk if nothing is found to be used as kickstart file. The desired kickstart option is the first option in the list, but until manually selected, the installation does not begin.

```
LABEL local
    MENU LABEL (local)
    MENU DEFAULT
    LOCALBOOT 0
```

**PXE default configuration file**

```
DEFAULT menu
PROMPT 0
MENU TITLE Cobbler | http://<customhostname> cobbler
TIMEOUT 200
TOTALTIMEOUT 6000
ONTIMEOUT $pxe_timeout_profile

$pxe_menu_items

MENU end
```

**grub2default configuration file for /etc/cobbler/pxe/**

```
set timeout=5

$pxe_menu_items
```

**screenshot showing the available options to select the kickstart  profile**
[image: Boot menu shown when used pxe]